# Join in biqquery with recent timestamp

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables in bigquery as below. I would like to select some columns by joining (left join) both the tables however I like the 'activity' column to be fetched from second table with the latest timestamp (top row based on latest time).

```
userId  age height
abc 34  160
xyz 32  170
```

```
userId  activity    time
abc running         10:45:00
abc walking         10:20:00
abc relax           10:10:00
```

Output should be like below

```
userId  age activity    time
abc 34  running         10:45:00
xyz 32  null            null
```

Please suggest the sql code in bigquery.

Thanks

Tried left join with row_num

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider below.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH users AS (
  SELECT 'abc' userId, 34 age, 160 height UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz', 32, 170
),
activities AS (
  SELECT 'abc' userId, 'running' activity, TIME '10:45:00' time UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', 'walking', '10:20:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abc', 'relax', '10:10:00'
)
-- query starts here
SELECT userId, age, activity.* 
  FROM users u 
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT userId, ANY_VALUE(STRUCT(activity, time) HAVING MAX time) activity
      FROM activities
     GROUP BY userId
  ) a USING (userId);
```

**query results**

[image]

- see also - [HAVING MAX](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate-function-calls#having_max) clause

Comment: Awesome @Jaytiger, that's worked perfectly in my environment. One more thing, if I want add another calculated column in the output table named as 'Time_since_last_activity' that should be 'current time - time', where should I add that piece of code?

Comment: you can add it as a field in the struct like `STRUCT(activity, time, current_time - time as time_since_last_activity)`